# inside Array.push without a function call

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to perform more logic before writing an element to an array:

```
tempDatensatz.push( () => {
    var current = window.dataForDataTable[i].outbounds[key].updatedAt;
    if (current) {
        return current.toString();
    } else {
        return "".toString();
    }
});
```

Getting the value from that array will be achieved like this:

```
tempDatensatz[0]()
```

But I want the same logic in it without having a function to call. I need a normal array, where I get a value like this:

```
tempDatensatz[0]
```

What can I do instead?

**Updated**
I published my project to gitHub, you can take a look if you need a better understanding :)
https://github.com/te2020/GoEuro/blob/master/GoEuro/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want `tempDatensatz[0]` to run the function?

Comment: @James Monger no without running a function, calling it like a normal array

Comment: What is `key`? A global constant?

Comment: @trincot `for (var key in window.dataForDataTable[i].outbounds) {if (window.dataForDataTable[i].outbounds.hasOwnProperty(key)) {...` I am reading a JSON-object

Comment: @JaneKins Indent your code properly, that's just plain lazy.

Comment: If you are addressing `window.dataForDataTable[i].outbounds.hasOwnProperty(key)` anyway, why do you need `tempDatensatz`? Please show enough context for us to understand what you are doing.

Comment: @trincot ok,  my aim is to fill a table(using datatables,net) and before doing so I want to format/do some work with the data(which is temporarly saved in `current `), which came from a server(`window.dataForDataTable`) . `tempDatensatz` is another array, which will be later(after some other work) assigned to datatables

Comment: Try to put yourself in our position. We don't know at all what you are doing. Please present code that shows what you are doing now, and explain what you want different. Up till you present bits and pieces, but the connection between them is unclear, so is what you want to do. For what I can see, I wonder why you don't fill `tempDatensatz` with the necessary data at once. The problem why you cannot do so is not explained. Please present more code that shows how you go from A to B.

Comment: put fiddle  then , let's discuss .

Comment: This question has 2 different answers depending on weather `window.dataForDataTable[i].outbounds[key].updatedAt` is constant or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use an **immediately invoked function** instead of just a function:

```
tempDatensatz.push( (function(){
    var current = window.dataForDataTable[i].outbounds[key].updatedAt;
    if (current) {
        return current.toString();
    } else {
        return "".toString();
    }
})());
```

The function will be executed immediatly after it definition, returning the result. So push won't `push` a reference to that function but instead it will push it returned value (the result).

Comment: Well, I have no clue about what precedes this code. Can you post the code that was before that? Is this inside a loop or not?

Comment: Just saw your code on github. This is not caused by my code. If it is then the code you provided in the question have something wrong. Fix it and update my function accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a proxy as follows:

```js
    function makeProxy(array) {
      return new Proxy(array, {
        get(target, property) { 
          return !isNaN(property) ? target[property]() : target[property];
        }
      });
    }

    const tempDatensatz = [];
    const useThisOne = makeProxy(tempDatensatz);

    useThisOne.push(() => alert("Hi, Jane!"));
    useThisOne[0];
```

Pushing/writing to the array will work as expected, but retrieving its elements will go through the `get` handler, which will execute the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an expression, like:

```
tempDatensatz.push( 
    (window.dataForDataTable[i].outbounds[key].updatedAt || '').toString();
);
```

For more complex expressions you can often use the ternary operator. For the above that would look like this:

```
tempDatensatz.push( 
    window.dataForDataTable[i].outbounds[key].updatedAt
       ? window.dataForDataTable[i].outbounds[key].updatedAt.toString()
       : ''
);
```

#### Your code

When looking at the [github code](https://github.com/te2020/GoEuro/blob/master/GoEuro/Views/Home/Index.cshtml) you linked to, you can do all that pushing with this "oneliner":

```
var tempDatensatz = 
    ['companyId', 'mode', 'duration', 'outboundId', 'journeyId', 'departureTime', 
     'arrivalTime', 'stops', 'price', 'updatedAt', 'segments']
        .map( prop => (window.dataForDataTable[i].outbounds[key][prop] || '').toString() );
```